# Laravel 5.4 passport to generate custom access token for API Authentication

Tags: php, access-token, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

We are trying to build an API service for our application which is going to be a single page application, and we came across Laravel Passport as mentioned in the documentation. We tried `Password Grant Tokens` which works well, but our requirement is to generate the access token using the data we get from LinkedIn after oAuth. For example, `linkedin_id`, `email` etc. Hence, we do not need a `username` and `password` fields (which are required for Password Grant Tokens).

We do not see any way to generate custom tokens in Laravel docs. Has anyone tried this? Or, is there any alternative to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Laravel Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite).
In Socialite you don't need username and password, only `client_id`, `cliend_secret` and `redirect_url` required.

```
'linkedIn' => [
    'client_id' => 'your-linkedIn-app-id',
    'client_secret' => 'your-linkedIn-app-secret',
    'redirect' => 'http://your-callback-url',
],
```